# ASP.NET MVC 4.5 - The issue with the Logon user (HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4.5.1 application using VS 2013.

Following are the settings at the IIS 7.5

1. Windows Authentication **Enabled** (also in Web.config **authentication** mode is set to "**Windows**").
2. Anonymous Authentication **Disabled**.
3. Application pool is running with service account "contoso\john".
4. The mode is **Integrated**.

On my landing page (e.g. HomeController.cs) I am storing logon user information as below:

**Session["LogonUserName"] = HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name** and that's working fine, I can use the Session["LogonUserName"] from other views.

However, when **redirecting** from home page to a different view e.g. Customer View something weird is happening and somehow I am **losing the authentication** and I am not able to step into a function.

So I Disabled the Windows Authentication and Enabled the Anonymous Authentication but then on the customer view page I am getting  **HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name = "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"**

and Session["LogonUserName"] = contoso\john, which is my **app pool account**.

Any idea why? Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The issue certainly due to be authentication (XSS problem) and the JavaScript code wasn't being trusted when running on localhost or on IP address. When given a DNS entry (site binding) the issue resolved.